# Beamer - frame break numbering style

Tags: beamer

How do I change the frame breaks numbering style?
I have lower case Roman at the moment but I'd like to change it to arabic.
I'm using the following code to break the frame:

`\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, noframenumbering, fragile]{Protocol}`

[image]

Comment: Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your next question.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the behaviour of the frame continuation with `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, noframenumbering, fragile]{Protocol}
    abc

    \vspace{20cm}
    edf 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you will be interested on this solution :-)

```
    \newcounter{cont}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
    \setcounter{cont}{\beamer@endpageofframe}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
    (\insertcontinuationcount/\arabic{cont})%
                                            }% end frame title continuation
\makeatother
```